# When another civ wins a single-player game of Civ 6, how do you tell who won and how?

Tags: civilization-6

When another civilization hits a victory condition (while your own civ is still around) in a single-player game of Civ 6, you get the blowing-dust video that tells you you lost, and can then review various stats for all civilizations in the game. But I can't see any way to find out which civilization won, and with what kind of victory. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Well, if you're the first Civ eliminated in a game, how would you expect there to be a winner when there's still several other Civs still around?

Comment: That's not the situation I'm talking about. My civilization is alive and well around turn 450, and suddenly I'm looking at the defeat video. Clearly, another civilization achieved a victory...but which civ, and what kind of victory?

Comment: Ah, that's some really important information that you should edit into your question. Because to me in Civ games, there's a distinction between "you lost" and "some other Civ won".

Comment: Ah, I think of both of them as just "losing", but you're right, clarity is good. I've edited my question title and content accordingly.

Comment: Late update: In the Civ 6 patch announcement today ( https://steamcommunity.com/games/289070/announcements/detail/562228356583764249 ), one of the patch descriptions is "Added additional information to Defeat/Victory screens, so players will be clearer on why they have lost the game." I haven't had a chance to lose a game with the new patch yet, but this certainly sounds like the problem I described has been solved.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I should report that yes, the 3/28 patch did indeed add reporting of who won and with what kind of victory to the end-of-game info home screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to numerous posts in [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/340412122419524923/) it looks like this was a design choice and the game will not tell you who won a game when you lose:

> Too bad there is no way to tell they reason you lost.

The best suggestion I have found so far was in [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/340412122418852698/):

> The way I figured it out - hit One More Turn and then go to the victory conditions screen (button on the top right). From there you can go to the "progress towards victory" tab and see who just won and why.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that thread; I didn't find it when I went looking. At least I'm not crazy. :)

Comment: I hope they make some improvements to the ending of the game. I liked the replay function of earlier versions. Other, more detailed analyses of the victor's particular path to victory would also be fun and would help me learn about effective strategies.

Comment: This may have changed since the answer, or possibly vary with victory type. When the AI won a science victory in my last game there was a message telling me this and which AI it was.